# Display errors decorator to many inputs with that same name in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I add many inputs with 'isArray' and name like foo, bar, baz etc.
one input[] to one group like this:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'foo', config with isArrat);
```

and in end of loop:

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(array('foo', 'bar'), 'group_'.$i,...)
```

etc. It works, and generates the form, but not display correct errors. I declare 'Errors' decorator to inputs and this decorator print error only in last input.

I want to print errors before all input with wrong data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I modyficate isValid()

```
$groups = $this->getDisplayGroups();
        $i=0;
        foreach($groups as $k => $v) {
            foreach ($v->getElements() as $key => $element) {
                ...
                $check = $data[$i];
```